# Why is my header off to the side?

Tags: html, css

I was just coding the header, really basic stuff. My header was off to the side, and I tried some stuff like

```
margin-left: -12px;
```

But I had heard that negative margins are bad for positioning things in CSS. As it isn't kind to some browsers.

Heres my code:

HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="header">

    </div>
</body>
```

And heres the CSS

```
#header {
  width: 1080px;
  margin: 0;
  height: 120px;
  background: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hxL5c/

You can obviously see the left of the header and the top have been pushed away form the edge.

Comment: add `body {margin:0; padding:0; }` to your css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reset the browser defaults:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

If you wanted to "normalize" your styles so that all browsers behave the same check out [normalize](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) which will help you keep your styles consistent.

Comment: Reason being that I chose this answer was that you added the normaliz.css, which I will have forever. Cuz the css helps alot. :) Thanks doe! Made my day!

Answer (score 1):

That is due to jsfiddle using body{} values.

If you check the css for the site, it has some pixels there.

Change your fiddle to include

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hxL5c/1/